# How would I go about finding a specific link in a website with python3

Tags: python, web-scraping

I'm trying to build a python program that scrapes this website: (https://fitgirl-repacks.site/dungeon-defenders-awakened/), and then return just the 1337x download link: (https://1337x.to/torrent/4474599/Dungeon-Defenders-Awakened-v1-0-0-17001-MULTi8-FitGirl-Repack/). I succeeded in scraping the website, but how would I go about coding up the program that finds the 1337x download link: (https://1337x.to/torrent/4474599/Dungeon-Defenders-Awakened-v1-0-0-17001-MULTi8-FitGirl-Repack/), and return it in the python console?.

Comment: which web scraping library are you using? what code are you using to scrape?

Comment: using `beautifulsoup` or `selenium` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using BeautifulSoup you can extract the url:

```
from requests import get
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

response = get('https://fitgirl-repacks.site/dungeon-defenders-awakened/')
html_text = response.text
html = BeautifulSoup(html_text)

tags = html.find_all("a", string="1337x")
first_tag = tags[0]
print(first_tag['href'])
```